# EF Code First, not generating database

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-migrations

I have an console application project in visual 2012. I want to use Entity Framework 6 code-first. when I run my project it does not create any database in my SQL Server. I am not able to create database by code first in my SQL Server.I am not getting any exception while build & run.

below is my code :

```
namespace CodeFirstNewDBeSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new BlogContext())
            {
                //Console.Write("Enter a name for new Blog:");
                //var name = Console.ReadLine();
                //var blog = new Blog { Name = name };
                //db.Blogs.Add(blog);
                //db.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }

    public class BlogContext : DbContext
    {
        public BlogContext() : base("name=BlogDBString") { }
        DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }


}
```

**Config File :**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BlogDBString" connectionString="data source=MY-PC;initial catalog=BlogDB;integrated security=True;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: @BassamAlugili : I am not getting any exception,it just not creating DB after execution.

Comment: BlogDBString check the table if no exception than the table must exist do you have SQL Server studio

Comment: Yes, I am using Sql Server 2012 & i can see that there is no DB created.

Comment: db.SaveChanges(); this code is working and no table is exist!!!???

Comment: I think your connection string not working correctly put a break point when the DbContext is created and check the given connection string I'm sure you will find the default connection string